# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
error in (bot.py, line 342 "send_to_location(js["location"],text)"): 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

код

```
def send_to_location(location, text):
for a in range(1,int(cfg.get('bot','users'))):
    i = cfg.get('!users',str(a))
    id = cfg.get('users',i)
    js = get_info(int(id))
    if location == js['location']:
        bot.send_message(int(id),text)
```

Comment: В `js` значение `None`

Comment: @gil9red как его получить?

Comment: @gil9red в js {"character": {"race": "human"}, "location": "start"}

Comment: У вас ошибка не в самой функции, а при вызове ее: `send_to_location(js["location"],text)`, на момент вызова `js = None`. Такие ошибки легко ловятся -- добавив `print` перед проблемой увидите когда случилось неожиданная ситуация

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка не в самой функции, а при вызове ее: `send_to_location(js["location"],text)`, на момент вызова `js = None`.

Такие ошибки легко ловятся -- добавив `print` перед проблемой увидите когда случилось неожиданная ситуация